# Remove background image from canvas in p5js before download/save canvas

Tags: javascript, html, p5.js

[image: image of problem]

I have an image as the canvas background in p5. Elements are drawn on top of the canvas background. but when I save/download the canvas, I want all the drawn elements to remain as is but have the background image deleted/erased. Any help would be appreciated.

Have tried to change the background image before download but it doesn't seem to work.

My code is below:

```
function setup() {
    canvas = createCanvas(width, height);
    canvas.parent('canvas-wrapper');
    bg = loadImage('images/grid.png');
}


function draw() {
    background(bg);
}


function keyPressed(){
    //if the key is a s
    if(key == 's'){
        //save out to a file
        saveCanvas(canvas, 'c', 'png');
    }
}

I am looking to delete/remove the grid.png image and make the background transparent while keeping the elements drawn on the canvas as is. Can someone please help!
```

Comment: With your current implementation, this is not an actual background image - it is just an image, which you paint onto your canvas first, before you paint other stuff on top of it. So you would either have to "reverse" that now, by going over your image pixel-by-pixel, and check if the color value is still the same as in that original image; or you need to record all of your drawing operations, so that you can repeat them in a "fresh" canvas without the background painted in first.

Comment: Or - you switch to an _actual_ background image, so that any still transparent pixels in your canvas simply let it "shine through".

Comment: Ok i understand what you are saying. But how do i switch to an actual bg image?

Comment: By setting a background-image via CSS?

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `bg` variable as `''` before saving. But wait for canvas to be drawn again by `draw` function at least one time, and then call `saveCanvas`. you can bring back the bg after exporting the canvas.

```js
function keyPressed() {
  //if the key is a s
  if (key == "s") {
    //save out to a file
    bg = "";
    setTimeout(() => {
      saveCanvas(canvas, "c", "png");
      bg = loadImage("images/grid.png");
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```